# SpringBoot: A controller extends another one but not detected

Tags: rest, spring-boot, controller

As the title said, the controller is inherited from another one with some common features that other controllers can use. However, the application could not detect the that controller and gave a 404 error for the route, while the Swagger UI is not showing it.

This is a **maven project** I created on another pc and cloned with git. It does not have problem when I ran it on that pc. On this pc, I tried to remove the inherited class, and it worked, but I would not leave it like that, since the inherited controller has the features like `ModelMapper` for DTO and `@RestController` that other controllers can use.

The **ProfileController** not showing in **profile** package:

```
package com.hanabinoir.portfolio.profile;

public class ProfileController extends BaseController {

    //...
}
```

The inherited **BaseController** in **infrastructure** package:

```
package com.hanabinoir.portfolio.infrastructure;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class BaseController {

    protected ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
}
```

I need the **ProfileController** showing correctly while inheriting the features from the **BaseController**. Please give me some suggestions if I had any problem on the project structure. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `@Inherited` Annotation in `@RestController`

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html

So your `ProfileController` has no annotations attached

You may want to define some custom annotation and use it for your needs

```
@Inherited
@RestController
public @interface InheritedRestController{
}

@InheritedRestController
public class BaseController {

}
```

Comment: There's `@Inheritance` annotation with specific strategies, but actually it's not used that way. The project became normal after I started up the pc today, I guess it was not clean before.